# function "onclick" is called even though it is not set in button

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code. I haven't been able able to figure out why click event occurs even though I haven't set the function to onclick attribute of button.

```js
var x = 0;
var onclick = function() {
  console.log("x = " + ++x);
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="">Click</button>
```

Comment: I can press the button but nothing is happening.

Comment: @suleiman Check your browser's console.

Barun var onclick same as window.onclick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you set global variable `onclick`, which translates to global object `window` property `onclick`. This is basically the same as if you were to set it directly:

```
window.onclick = function() {
    console.log("x = " + ++x);
};
```

And because you have set click event on entire `window` object, it will fire not only on button click but on click on anything within your document (unless event propagation is stopped).

Comment: [*event.stopPropragation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) only stops it going past the listener, it doesn't stop it getting to the listener (since it can only be called from a listener, it must get to the listener first). So "*…unless event propragation is stopped by some other click listener beforehand*". ;-)

Comment: Even if you "define" it with `var`? That's good to know. I think I could have made the same mistake as the OP!

Comment: @MrLister Well in this case we are in global scope, so `var` sets global variable. If this code was inside a function, then it would not set `window.onclick` of course.

Answer (score 0):

As @dfsq mentioned, you're creating `window.onclick` when you do `var onclick=`. On a similar note:

```js
var onerror = function() {
  console.log("ERROR HAPPENED!");
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="ThisFunctionIsNotDefined()">Click</button>
```